# Sony Remote Camera API: use in AP environments

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I have a Sony A7S2 - is there a way to access the Remote Camera API endpoint while the camera is connected to an access point - and, while we're at it: is it possible to keep the camera connected to an AP and the endpoint running all the time, even during "normal" operation? As soon as I exit the WiFi menu, the camera disconnects from the AP.

Reason: I'd like to control my camera from way more far away than the integrated AP allows, and I'd like to be able to control the camera while also connected to the Internet (so I can upload transferred photos without having to switch my laptop's WiFi connection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately with the camera Remote API you will only be able to connect directly to the camera to control it. This issue has been raised with the team though and we will for sure post an update if anything changes.

As far as keeping the camera connected, this does vary from camera to camera, but generally there is no way to extend the wifi connection period beyond the default time.

Comment: Has this since changed? Hardwired control of the camera is a critical feature in aerial use. WiFi is too unreliable and the Multiconnector hack doesn't provide enough features. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Robert, I hope you are still active. Has this issue led anywhere in the last year?

Comment: Hi @skynet. Unfortunately the Camera Remote API is no longer under development so there won't be any update on this for the foreseeable future. I apologize for the impact on your development.

Answer (score 0):

Sony's A7-series supports the PTP/IP protocol when connected to an AP, e.g., for downloading files through the wireless importer. You cannot use the remote-API through that but it might or might not support PTP's build-in capture commands (never tried...).

Comment: Hmm nice but how do I keep the camera connected while shooting?

Comment: You mean while operating it by hand? Don't think that's possible.

Comment: Well, actually not shooting by hand, rather "stick the camera with a USB power supply and a wifi connection active somewhere, trigger it by wifi and transfer photos/videos by wifi"

Comment: Ok, that's what I meant. You can connect the camera to an AP and then connect to it from a host using PTP/IP (need to go into "send to computer" mode). I'm doing that to transfer raw-shots off the camera wirelessly (as does Sony's WirelessAutoImporter). 
PTP/IP defines an "InitiateCapture" command and also let's you set all kinds of properties (ISO, shutter speed, ...). I have never tried if Sony has implemented that command (I just use the file transfer ones). If they have, it would probably address your use case.

Comment: If you feel like experimenting, you could use [my Java PTP/IP library](https://github.com/Fimagena/libptp), which is tested with Sony's A7 cameras. You would have to get the spec to extend the library to the InitiateCapture command, which should be trivial (notwithstanding having to go through my sparsely documented code).
If you do, please share back.

Comment: Add-on: I got curious, implemented the command myself and tested with the A7RIII. Result: It does **not** support capture commands over PTP/IP. The camera can actually list its supported commands and InitiateCapture is not included.